# Can groups be irreps of themselves?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups, group-actions

A very simple question. If you define the $D_4$ group to be defined by matrices generated by the matrices
$$ \sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}, \ \ \epsilon = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ then you find that it has 5 irreps - 4 1D irreps and 1 2D irrep which just uses the same matrices as above.

Can we therefore say that the $D_4$ group 'is an irrep of itself'. Or is this a dangerous way of phrasing it. If so, why?

Comment: A group representation is not a group, but a homomorphism from a group to a general linear group. So it would not be correct (or a good idea) to refer to this group of matrices as a representation of itself. You could say that identity map on this group is an irreducible representation.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense!